# Can Mathematica be run on Windows subsystem for Linux

Tags: windows, linux

I went back and forth if this question should be asked, but decided to ask it anyways.

Is it possible to run Mathematica (command line version) from the [developer mode linux in W10](http://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/)?

Comment: Can you explain what you have tried so far? And what the issues were?

Comment: @felix I'm running W8. I can upgrade one of my desktops if that shows accurate effort for the question but can't try as I stand.

Comment: @Felix I can't tell if its you who down voted but would it be an acceptable question to ask how to establish a link between mathematica windows version and the new Windows subsystem for Linux?  Windows has a more stable interface(slightly) and would give you the best of both worlds.

Comment: Nobody down voted your question. I am actually just now trying to install it. However, you could still improve your question and indicate what exactly you try to achieve. From your last comment it seems that you don't necessarily want to run *Mathematica* in the Linux shell. So what is it that you want? Exchanging files? Call Linux software within *Mathematica*?

Comment: @Felix I meant close voted not downvoted.  I want access to the command line tools mainly & .NETLink at the same time.  There is no such thing as .NETLink in linux obviously and linux is lacking the command line interfaces.

Comment: ... There is JavaLink which I am not a fan.  It for whatever reason even with a SSD seems to run slow for me anyways.

Comment: Actually there is `.NETLink` in Linux, you have to install the mono `C#` compiler.

Comment: @RunnyKine there is no way I trust mono c# after the few times I have used it.

Comment: Well, I've used it for over 7 years with no problems and Microsoft trusts it, so I don't know why you don't.

Comment: @RunnyKine it is more stable then the JavaLink?  Also there were apis missing last time I tried it.

Comment: You need to install the complete mono framework e.g. sudo apt-get install mono-complete. That should give you the full apis

Comment: @RunnyKine I tried it quite a long time ago I think before the microsoft trusted it so I will try again thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to install and run *Mathematica* in the Linux shell of Windows 10. I had some minor issues, described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/405800/installation-problem-xdg-desktop-menu-no-writable-system-menu-directory-found), [here](http://iamnotmyself.com/2016/07/13/windows-subsystem-for-linux-error-unable-to-resolve-host-2/), [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/4ea4w4/fyi_you_can_run_gui_linux_apps_from_bash/), and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302683/omp-error-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows). To summarize those links, I had to

- create the directory `/usr/share/desktop-directories/`
- add my hostname to `/etc/hosts` (not strictly speaking related to *Mathematica*)
- install an X-server (xming) and start the X-server
- add `export DISPLAY=:0` and `export KMP_AFFINITY=disabled` to my `~/.bashrc`

I could not really test any features because I already used by license key but at least I can confirm that the pop-up requesting the key opens correctly.